# PrintWriter--No Output?

Tags: java

EDIT: Fixed!  Was overwriting file instead of appending to the file.

I seem to have a bit of a problem trying to use a PrintWriter to add a "header" to a log file before use, so that my program knows that it is not just a random text file.  The field output_file refers to an argument taken by the logger initialization function to set the log file, whereas log_file is a static file field for the (global and static) logging class.  After opening the log file to check for errors, *there is no header.*  Using logging functions, also carried out by a PrintWriter, gives the correct output.  Am I doing something wrong?  (I know I am reinventing the wheel as a logging API already exists for Java, but I am working on a learning exercise.)

```
//After testing to make sure the file specified does not exist
log_file=output_file; 
output_file.createNewFile();
PrintWriter pw=new PrintWriter(log_file);
pw.println("**[PROGRAM_NAME Log]**");
pw.flush();
pw.close();
isInitialized=true;
```

EDIT: The file is definitely writable, or the logger itself wouldn't work.  Also, for those who were wondering, the code to log something is the following (Same general method as writing the header AKA new PrintWriter(log_file);)

```
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(log_file);
pw.print("[INFO:] " + sdf.format(new Date())); //The variable sdf is a date formatter for timestamps.
pw.println(" " + message);
pw.close();
```

Comment: You seem to be logging to a `PrintWriter` from the `log_file` but the actual file is created (`createNewFile()`) from the `output_file`... is this correct?

Comment: @ochi but the two variables reference the same object.

Comment: The -hard disk- file is created by the createNewFile(), yes, but log_file and output_file are essentially the same thing here.  (log_file=output_file;)

Comment: You said that logging is also carried out by a PrintWriter. Do you by any chance use `new PrintWriter(log_file)` there, too?

Comment: Could you try `if (!log_file.setWritable(true)) throw new Exception("cannot write to file");` before writing anything and add the result to your post?

Comment: So why have the two variables at all? What is undoubtedly happening is that the first log event opens the log file in overwrite mode rather than append mode. NB you dont't need to call `createNewFile()` here either. `new PrintWriter()` already does that, and so clearly does the first log event.

Comment: I guess it really depends on either permissions or how the global logging class is initialized after you create your file and log your header.  If the directory does not exist when you try to create your file it won't get created and if the global logging class detects this, it might create it for you (but then your header never was written on such file) - your code, as is, seems to work: http://goo.gl/NUxkUG

Comment: It may be that you're over-writing instead of appending; you write the header, CLOSE the file, and then the logging calls write over that header ...

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation for `PrintWriter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#PrintWriter%28java.io.File%29) says:

> `file` - The file to use as the destination of this writer. If the file
>   exists then it will be truncated to zero size; otherwise, a new file
>   will be created. The output will be written to the file and is
>   buffered.

So every time you use `new Printwriter(log_file)`, you are actually truncating the file, erasing everything in it, and starting fresh.

This means, of course, that as soon as you start logging, the header data gets erased.

If you want to *append* to the file, rather than erase it every time, you need to open a `FileOutputStream` with the `append` option, and open the `PrintWriter` on top of it.

```
    try ( 
        FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(log_file, true);
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(os);
    ) {
        pw.println("Your log line here");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

(Note the use of try-with-resources to auto-close the file when work with it is done. Of course, you can just keep it opened until you finish logging. This is merely an example.).